# Image uploading laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I'm working in file uploading inlaravel but i'm struck in coding while uploading file. Image is not storing in the location but tha name is saving in the database
here is my controller.php

```
$contact = new Contact;
            $contact->name   =       Input::get('name');
            $contact->email   =       Input::get('email');
            $contact->mobile   =       Input::get('mobile');
            $contact->password   =       Input::get('password');
            $contact->confirm   =       Input::get('confirm');
            $contact->upload=$data['avatar'];
            $time=time();
            if(Input::hasFile('avatar'))
            {
                $contact = Input::file('avatar');
                $img=$time . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $contact->move('../app/uploads', $img);   
            }$contact -> save();
```

view.blade.php is

```
{{ Form::file('avatar') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your if statement if not true. also you can try replacing $content inside the if statement with $file.